# How to get text and select text from a list box in another application using VBA with the help of win32 API

Tags: vba, winapi

I am trying to get text from a list box in another application using VBA, so that I can select a certain selection in the list box, if the text is matched. I have the following code that doesn't work. Every time I ran the code the application crashed. I was trying to search on google for solution, but had no luck. If anyone has any solution, please help.

```
Do
    DoEvents
    vendor_listbox = FindWindowEx(Client_window, 0&, "ListBox", vbNullString)
Loop Until vendor_listbox > 0
numberofindex = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, ByVal 0&)
TopIndex = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0)

For i = TopIndex To numberofindex - 1
    textcount = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTEXTLEN, i, 0)
    buffer$ = Space$(textcount + 1)
    Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTEXT, i, buffer$)
    Debug.Print buffer$
    'This code does not work
    Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox,LB_SETCURSEL,i, 0&)
    'I have tried this too, but also didn't work
    Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox,LB_SELECTSTRING,0&, ByVal buffer$
    Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox,BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)
Next i
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to use UI Automation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , i heard a lot about UI Automation. but none has given an example.

Comment: @milevyo websearch for one

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i quote "Wouldn't it be simple to use UI Automation?" if UI automation is simpler than the OP's given code, it would be easy too to give a sample. why complicate things with websearch search?, at least give a link.

Comment: @milevyo I personally don't find websearch to be that complicated

Comment: @DavidHeffernan be sure i have nothing personal against you, that was just  a talk. i just wanted to enrich this site with one useful code about UI automation. thats all

Answer (score 1):

correct this

```
Do
    DoEvents
    vendor_listbox = FindWindowEx(Client_window, 0&, "ListBox", vbNullString)
Loop Until vendor_listbox > 0
numberofindex = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, ByVal 0&)
TopIndex = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0)

For i = TopIndex To numberofindex - 1
    textcount = SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTEXTLEN, i, 0)
   'space for null terminating string '\0' will be automatically added by VB
    buffer$ = Space$(textcount ) 
    ' pass string byval not byref 
    ' also make sure that lParam of SendMessage is declared as ANY
    Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_GETTEXT, i, byval buffer$)
    Debug.Print buffer$
Next i
```

Comment: I have tried another step with selecting the item in the listbox, but it seems nothing working. I added the following code to select eatch item and sendmessage to the Ok button.

        Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_SELECTSTRING, 0, ByVal buffer$)
        Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, BM_CLICK, 0&, ByVal 0&)
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Comment: @BunrithHeng it is not clear for me what you want, you can always reedit your post, and explain exactly the desired behavior and results.

Comment: I would like to select an option in the listbox of another application and send it as input by clicking on OK button in that application window.
I have tried using the code bellow.

Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_SELECTSTRING, 0, ByVal buffer$)

And I have also tried

Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_SETCURSEL, i, ByVal 0&)

The code did not send selection to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same trouble like me, here is my solution to select and send the selection as input to the program. I am trying to avoid using sendkeys, but I couldn't find the solution to it.

```
Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_SETSEL, ByVal 0&, ByVal -1&)
Call SendMessage(vendor_listbox, LB_SETSEL, ByVal 1&, ByVal 5&)
BringWindowToTop hinv_window
Application.SendKeys "{UP}", True
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```